How to make a tensor diagram out of quiver code?
I need to make a string/tensor diagram (something like this) out of this diagram made with https://q.uiver.app/:

Here is the corresponding latex code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{quiver}


    \begin{document}
    \[\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&, column sep = 1em]
        \&\&\&\&\&\&\&\&\& A \\
        \&\&\&\&\&\&\&\&\& {\cdot_A} \\
        \&\&\&\&\&\&\&\& A \&\& A \\
        \&\& A \&\&\&\&\&\& \delta \\
        \&\& \delta \&\&\&\&\& S \\
        \&\&\&\&\& {=} \&\& \phi \&\&\& \delta \\
        \&\&\& M \&\&\& S \&\& S \&\& M \&\& M \\
        \&\&\& \bigoplus \&\&\&\& \Delta \&\&\&\& \Delta \\
        S \&\& M \&\& M \&\&\& S \&\& M \&\& M
        \arrow[no head, from=2-10, to=1-10]
        \arrow[no head, from=3-9, to=2-10]
        \arrow[no head, from=3-11, to=2-10]
        \arrow[no head, from=4-9, to=3-9]
        \arrow[no head, from=5-3, to=4-3]
        \arrow[no head, from=5-8, to=4-9]
        \arrow[no head, from=6-8, to=5-8]
        \arrow[no head, from=6-11, to=3-11]
        \arrow[no head, from=7-4, to=5-3]
        \arrow[no head, from=7-7, to=6-8]
        \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,214}, no head, from=7-9, to=6-11]
        \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,92;green,92;blue,214}, no head, from=7-11, to=6-8]
        \arrow[no head, from=7-13, to=6-11]
        \arrow[no head, from=8-4, to=7-4]
        \arrow[no head, from=8-8, to=7-7]
        \arrow[no head, from=8-8, to=7-9]
        \arrow[no head, from=8-12, to=7-11]
        \arrow[no head, from=8-12, to=7-13]
        \arrow[no head, from=9-1, to=5-3]
        \arrow[no head, from=9-3, to=8-4]
        \arrow[no head, from=9-5, to=8-4]
        \arrow[no head, from=9-8, to=8-8]
        \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, curve={height=6pt}, no head, from=9-10, to=4-9]
        \arrow[no head, from=9-12, to=8-12]
    \end{tikzcd}\]
    \end{document}

Please note that you need to have an additional file quiver.sty in your directory to do \usepackage{quiver} which can be found here

Hm, can you please add a screenshot to your question: what does your code produce? Also: what is your question? Thank you

This seems to be a content question rather than about TeX. Is this homework? Can you add a picture of what the output should look like and the code you've tried to produce it? Or maybe it should be on Maths SE?

You don't need quiver.sty and you should change the curve option to bend right=5.
The code can be simplified a lot.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep = 1em,arrows=no head]
  &&&&&&&&& A \\
  &&&&&&&&& {\cdot_A} \\
  &&&&&&&& A && A \\
  && A &&&&&& \delta \\
  && \delta &&&&& S \\
  &&&&& {=} && \phi &&& \delta \\
  &&& M &&& S && S && M && M \\
  &&& \oplus &&&& \Delta &&&& \Delta \\
  S && M && M &&& S && M && M
  \arrow[from=2-10, to=1-10]
  \arrow[from=3-9, to=2-10]
  \arrow[from=3-11, to=2-10]
  \arrow[from=4-9, to=3-9]
  \arrow[from=5-3, to=4-3]
  \arrow[from=5-8, to=4-9]
  \arrow[from=6-8, to=5-8]
  \arrow[from=6-11, to=3-11]
  \arrow[from=7-4, to=5-3]
  \arrow[from=7-7, to=6-8]
  \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,214}, from=7-9, to=6-11]
  \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,92;green,92;blue,214}, from=7-11, to=6-8]
  \arrow[from=7-13, to=6-11]
  \arrow[from=8-4, to=7-4]
  \arrow[from=8-8, to=7-7]
  \arrow[from=8-8, to=7-9]
  \arrow[from=8-12, to=7-11]
  \arrow[from=8-12, to=7-13]
  \arrow[from=9-1, to=5-3]
  \arrow[from=9-3, to=8-4]
  \arrow[from=9-5, to=8-4]
  \arrow[from=9-8, to=8-8]
  \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, bend right=5, from=9-10, to=4-9]
  \arrow[from=9-12, to=8-12]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}


